# Error Encountering in Creating New Controller in ASP Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm having a problem in creating my new controller inside the "Controllers" folder provided by ASP.Net MVC API. I don't know how can I fix this thing. I already rebuild all solutions. But when I clicked the "Add" button the error says

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/visual-studio-2015-there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-aaarrrhhhggghhh: Try deleting the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs` folder.

Comment: When I checked the Temporary ASP.NET Files, it's already empty though.